# JAVA - Add to arrayList a String

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to send to a ArrayList Strings that come from the user input:

```
private static void adicionarReserva() {
    Scanner adiciona = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Numero da pista: ");
        int nPista = adiciona.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Numero de jogadores: ");
        int nJogadores = adiciona.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Data Inicio: ");
        String data_inicio = adiciona.next();

    Reservas reserva = new Reservas(nPista, data_inicio);
    ArrayList<Jogadores> nome_jogador = new ArrayList(); 

    for (int i=1;i<=nJogadores;i++) {
        System.out.println("Nome Jogador: ");
        String nome = adiciona.next();
        nome_jogador.add(nome);
    }

    reserva.addJogadores(nome_jogador);

}
```

In my Class called: Reservas, i have this:

```
public void addJogadores(Jogadores lista_jogadores) {
    this.lista_jogadores.add(lista_jogadores);
}
```

But i have this error:

```
nome_jogador.add(nome);
```

> The method add(Jogadores) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (String)

And this one:

```
reserva.addJogadores(nome_jogador);
```

> The method addJogadores(Jogadores) in the type Reservas is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList)

Any one can help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very meaningful error you're getting.

This is your `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList<Jogadores> nome_jogador = new ArrayList(); 
          ↑
```

What are you trying to insert to it? a `String`, but it suppose to have `Jogadores` in it.

Now look at your `addJogadores` method signature:

```
public void addJogadores(Jogadores lista_jogadores)
                         ↑
```

It accepts `Jogadoers` object and not an `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass an instance of class `Jogadores`, if `Jogadores` has a constructor which accepts a `String` then:

```
nome_jogador.add(new Jogadores(nome));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<Jogadores> nome_jogador = new ArrayList();
```

You are only allowed to add objects that are an instance of `Jogadores` and because you are trying to add a `String` (which is obviously not an instance of `Jogadores`) it gives you an error.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static void adicionarReserva() {
    Scanner adiciona = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Numero da pista: ");
        int nPista = adiciona.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Numero de jogadores: ");
        int nJogadores = adiciona.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Data Inicio: ");
        String data_inicio = adiciona.next();

    Reservas reserva = new Reservas(nPista, data_inicio);
    ArrayList<Jogadores> nome_jogador = new ArrayList(); 

    for (int i=1;i<=nJogadores;i++) {
        System.out.println("Nome Jogador: ");
        String nome = adiciona.next();
        nome_jogador.add(new Jogadores(nome));
    }

    reserva.addJogadores(nome_jogador);

}
```

In your Class called: Reservas

```
public void addJogadores(ArrayList<Jogadores> lista_jogadores) {
    this.lista_jogadores.addAll(lista_jogadores);
}
```